# Query syntax issue

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I have some code written by someone else. This code is giving me a syntax error and I cannot figure out why.

```
if (!isset($_POST['new'])) {$query.= 'WHERE `name` ="'.mysqli_real_escape_string($origName).'"';}
$query .= ';';
query($query);
$output = "Changes saved";
```

The specific error is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `name` =""' at line 1

I am hoping someone here can point out the obvious to me.

Thanks for the suggestions, but still getting the same basic error.  Here is the chunk of code that deals with adding a new person:

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {    // Save new/updated presenter
    $newName = mysqli_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['name'],ENT_QUOTES));
    $origName = mysqli_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['origName'],ENT_QUOTES));

    if (isset($_POST['new'])) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO `presenters` SET `name`='$newName'";
    } else {
        $query = "UPDATE `presenters` SET `name`='$newName'";
    }
    unset($_POST['new'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['origName']);
    foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
        $key = mysql_real_escape_string($key);
        $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
        $query .= ", `$key`='$value'";
    }
    if (!isset($_POST['new'])) {
    $query.= "WHERE `name` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $origName) . "'";
    }
    $query .= ';';
    query($query);
    $output = "Changes saved";
```

Comment: Can you add the generated query? I assume that there is no space before `WHERE`.

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string()` expect two parameters.

Comment: Care to share the complete **generated** SQL code? Or you're trying to run SQL that **starts** with `WHERE`?

Comment: From the PHP Docs: _"string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )"_ You're missing the `mysqli $link` parameter...

Comment: Just noticing .. `unset($_POST['new']....)` and later ` if (!isset($_POST['new'])) {` ... Always true, not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean formatting helps clean stuff like this up:

```
if (!isset($_POST['new'])) {
  $query.= "WHERE `name` = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($origName) . "'";
}
$query .= ';';
query($query);
$output = "Changes saved";
```

First, the formatting of the `WHERE` in your example is off. I set that to double quotes for the whole query & single quotes for the value inside the query that comes from `mysqli_real_escape_string($origName)`.

But that said, the [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) format is incorrect. For the procedural style you need to have the actual DN connection (aka: link) set as the first parameter:

```
string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )
```

So the `mysqli_real_escape_string()` as shown in your example needs to be changed to something like this:

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $origName)
```

With `$db` actually being the real MySQL database connection link in your larger code structure.

Answer (score 0):

Probably just need to add a space in front of the `WHERE`

```
if (!isset($_POST['new'])) {$query.= ' WHERE `name` ="'.mysqli_real_escape_string($origName).'"';}
```

Could also be the double quotes, I believe MySQL uses single quotes around strings.

```
if (!isset($_POST['new'])) {$query.= " WHERE `name` ='".mysqli_real_escape_string($origName)."'";}
```

Comment: weird, my version 5.1.73 (just tested it) only works with single quotes. Double quotes causes it to think it's a variable/column name

Comment: You might have [`ANSI QUOTES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) turned on. Normally this is not the case. Also, if you're still using 5.1 you're missing out on some massive performance improvements.

Comment: edit: my bad, a deployment script added `sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES'` to my config

Comment: CentOS 6.5 ships with MySQL 5.1 only :<, and I don't want to deviate too much from production environment

Comment: That's shamefully out of date. MySQL 5.5 shipped in 2009 and MySQL 5.6 is the current stable version, it was released in 2011.

Comment: Well, RHEL, and subsequently CentOS, is usually at least a few years behind latest versions for "stability" reasons...

Comment: It's probably because RedHat is migrating to [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/) instead of MySQL. Worth checking out as an alternative.

Comment: Not sure where PHP came from... but yea Centos ships with PHP 5.3.3 by default right now.

Comment: MySQL.com now has its own yum repo you can use to install on CentOS (they only say that they support RHEL and Oracle Linux, but I use CentOS and it works fine). http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/

Answer (score 0):

Though your first two `mysqli_real_escape_string()`s also need 2 parameters. The first one should be your db-link, the second one the string that needs to be escaped.

The use of `htmlentities()` can be removed inside `mysqli_real_escape_string()`